# SmtpClientAuthenticationException (Incorrect username / password / credentials) error of mailer in flutter

Tags: flutter, mailer

Please anyone can help to resolve this Error in my flutter project. there is a main problem which is that if, i am running my project directly with command "flutter run". it is running perfectly but. If, i run with debugging then gives the above error and one more which i am sharing below.

1. pubspec.yml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  mailer: ^3.0.4
```

2. here is main file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mail_example/mail.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Mail Example"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await mail();
              },
              child: Text("send Mail"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

3. code of sending mail

```
import 'package:mailer/mailer.dart';
import 'package:mailer/smtp_server.dart';

Future mail() async {
  String username = 'myemialaddress@gmail.com';
  String password = 'mymailpassword';

  final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
  // Use the SmtpServer class to configure an SMTP server:
  // final smtpServer = SmtpServer('smtp.domain.com');
  // See the named arguments of SmtpServer for further configuration
  // options.

  // Create our message.
  final message = Message()
    ..from = Address(username, 'name in mail address')
    ..recipients.add('secondmailid') // where i am sending test message.
    ..subject = 'Test Dart Mailer library'
    ..text = 'This is the plain text.This is line 2 of the text part.';

  try {
    final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
    print('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
  } on MailerException catch (e) {
    print('Message not sent.');
    for (var p in e.problems) {
      print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
    }
  }
  // DONE
  // Sending multiple messages with the same connection
  //
  // Create a smtp client that will persist the connection
  var connection = PersistentConnection(smtpServer);

  // Send the first message
  await connection.send(message);

  // close the connection
  await connection.close();
}
```

4. errors during run on debugging.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on CPH1911 in debug mode...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterActivity(18500): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(18500): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(18500): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(18500): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
D/FlutterView(18500): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@c57f787
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(18500): Executing Dart entrypoint: main, and sending initial route: /
D/FlutterView(18500): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@c57f787
I/flutter (18500): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (18500): The following assertion was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, dependencies:
I/flutter (18500): [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#abd0a], _InheritedTheme], state: _MyHomePageState#c4844):
I/flutter (18500): type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '() => void'
I/flutter (18500):
I/flutter (18500): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (18500): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (18500): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (18500):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter (18500):
I/flutter (18500): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (18500):   MyHomePage
[38;5;248mI/flutter (18500):[39;49m
I/flutter (18500):
I/flutter (18500): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
[38;5;248mI/flutter (18500): #0      _MyHomePageState.build[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #1      StatefulElement.build[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #2      ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #3      Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #4      ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #5      StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #6      ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #7      Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #8      Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #9      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #10     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #11     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #13     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #14     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #15     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #16     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #17     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #18     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #19     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #20     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #22     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #23     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #24     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #25     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #26     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #27     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #28     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #29     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #30     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #31     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #32     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #33     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #35     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #36     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #37     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #38     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #39     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #40     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #41     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #42     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #43     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #44     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #45     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #46     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #47     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #48     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #49     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #50     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #51     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #52     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #53     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #54     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #55     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #56     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #57     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #58     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #59     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #60     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #61     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #62     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #63     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #64     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #65     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #66     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #67     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #68     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #69     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #70     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #71     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #72     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #73     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #74     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #75     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #76     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #77     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #78     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #79     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #80     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #81     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #82     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #83     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #84     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #85     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #86     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #87     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #88     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #89     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #90     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #91     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #92     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #93     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #94     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #95     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #96     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #97     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #98     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #99     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #100    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #101    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #102    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #103    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #104    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #105    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #106    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #107    _TheatreElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #108    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #109    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #110    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #111    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #112    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #113    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #114    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #115    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #116    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #117    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #118    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #119    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #120    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #121    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #122    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #123    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #124    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #125    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #126    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #127    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #128    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #129    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #130    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #131    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #132    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #133    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #134    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #135    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #136    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
E/flutter (18500): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid message.
[38;5;248mE/flutter (18500): #0      _validate[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter (18500): #1      send[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter (18500): #2      mail[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter (18500): #3      _MyHomePageState.build[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #4      StatefulElement.build[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #6      Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #7      ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #9      ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #10     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #11     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #12     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #13     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #14     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #16     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #17     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #18     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #19     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #20     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #22     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #23     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #24     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #25     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #26     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #27     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #28     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #29     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #30     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #31     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #32     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #33     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #35     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #36     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #37     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #38     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #39     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #40     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #41     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #42     ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #43     StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #44     ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #45     Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (18500): #46     Element.updateChild[39;49m
E/flutter (18500): #47     ComponentElement.performRebuild (pac
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #137    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #138    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #139    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #140    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #141    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #142    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #143    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #144    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #145    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #146    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #147    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #148    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #149    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #150    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #151    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #152    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #153    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #154    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #155    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #156    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #157    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #158    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #159    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #160    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #161    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #162    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #163    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #164    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #165    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #166    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #167    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #168    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #169    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #170    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #171    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #172    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #173    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #174    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #175    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #176    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #177    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #178    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #179    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #180    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #181    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #182    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #183    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #184    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #185    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #186    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #187    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #188    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #189    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #190    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #191    StatefulElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #192    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #193    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #194    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #195    ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #196    Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #197    ComponentElement._firstBuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #198    ComponentElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #199    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #200    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #328    Element.inflateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #329    Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #330    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #331    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #332    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #333    BuildOwner.buildScope[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #334    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #335    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #336    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #345    _Timer._runTimers  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:384:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #346    _Timer._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)[39;49m
[38;5;244mI/flutter (18500): #347    _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)[39;49m
I/flutter (18500): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async and package dart:async-patch)
```

I know it is working with command flutter run. but i need to sure. if, i deploy my app on google play and apple store. it work perfectly.
Your answer will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Go and turn off security of google account from which you are sending mail :
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: I was getting same although using correct username and password but using one setting everything working fine now..  Go to Settings>Forwarding and POP/IMAP > Enable IMAP access , it will not show any error now